# Problema al crear password en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, server

estoy instalando MySQl y me pide ingresar un password del usuario, pensé que lo tenía que crear pero cuando lo intento y le doy a check, me dice **Could not connect to MySQl with the given password**

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

Dato: Ya tenía instalado MySQl antes, pero lo desinstalé todo y lo volví a instalar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta dejándolo en blanco. Muchas veces la clave del usuario `root` es vacía por defecto. Es evidente que luego puedes/debes cambiarla por una clave segura.

Answer (score 0):

Se que llego tarde pero justo hoy he tenido el mismo problema y era porque:

- Al principio:

Cuando te indica donde se va a instalar el programa y sus dependencias, te suele salir una alerta donde dice: ya existe un folder con este nombre en esta ubicacion, ¿seguro que desea continuar?
Entonces, al darle que si, que es lo que hice yo, te sale esa pesataña de la contraseña donde no deja poner ninguna.

No se si es algun problea de sql donde no te indica el porque de no continuar pero se soluciona muy rápido.

- Entonces:

Desinstala tooooodo lo que tenga que ver con mySQL en tu pc. Normalmente esta en **C:\ProgramData**, en **C:\Program Files** y en **C:\Program Files (x86)**.

Cuando vuelvas a ejecutar el instalador, (si te sale que es encesrio la version 13,15 o 19 de VSC da igual, eso se puede cambiar en el propio IDE) dale todo a continuar y al ejecutar las primeras dependencias ya se pondran todas en verde sin necesidad de darle refrescar.

Y te saldrá esta interfaz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que si siguen con este problema te lo solucione y un gran saludo.